# What is the fastest velocity that has been observed for an atom?

Tags: special-relativity, electrons, speed-of-light, atoms, particle-accelerators

I know that particle accelerators have sent electrons to velocities that are significant percentages of the speed of light.

My question is instead, have they done the same with atoms? And do the atomic forces (gravity, charge, etc), hold at these velocities?

The intuition is that gravity appears to have a velocity (i.e., its force carrier) of exactly $c$. If this is the case, then gravity should break down as an atom approaches the speed of light, since the force carrier won't make it in time to reach, e.g., the electrons from the nucleus.

This has plainly been downvoted, and I'm a bit disappointed, because this site is usually quite good, and perhaps it's my fault for not explaining the reason I asked the follow up question about the atomic forces:

You do have states of matter beyond the atom at extremely high temperatures, where you have plasmas etc -

How you can outright dismiss the possibility that this is due to atomic forces breaking down?

This is mainstream physics, that perhaps needed a bit of a clarification, which is what I usually find on this site, and if this gripe is inappopriate, feel free to remove it, just leave the bit about plasmas.

Comment: Voting to close as not about mainstream physics, as in mainstream physics I don't think any of these predictions would hold?

Comment: One, atoms are neutral, you couldn't accelerate them, you'd have to make them into ions first. And two gravity has little to do with the integrity of atoms.

Comment: The electromagnetic force between a proton and an electron is ~10⁴⁰ times stronger than the gravitational force between them. See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/637799/123208

Comment: I think question should stay. Someone will simply tell him about rest mass. Sometimes people dont know what they dont know. Plus there is also a pretty coherent question of how fast an “atom” has gone.  Im curious.

Comment: " since the force carrier won't make it in time to reach, e.g., the electrons from the nucleu" You have a classical model in mind with this  statement. Atoms are bound quantum mechanically. and their binding is Lorentz  transformation invariant

Comment: *"since the force carrier won't make it in time to reach"* Why not? Even without the extra complication of relativity, a signal travelling at lightspeed can always catch up with an object travelling at less than lightspeed. And if an atom is travelling near lightspeed (relative to some observer), why would that affect the velocity of its electrons relative to its nucleus?

Comment: You might research the temperature at which a gas becomes a plasma.

Answer (score 4):

The Brookhaven Relativistic Heavy Ion Accelerator routinely propels gold ions to nearly the speed of light. All the physical laws we know about hold true for the heavy ions under these conditions.

Your intuition about gravity is wrong. From the frame of reference of the heavy ion after it has been accelerated, its (captive) electrons are traveling right along at the same speed that the nucleus is.

Answer (score 0):

The fastest atoms that have been accurately observed would be the protons in the LHC.

LHC accelerates a proton (stripped Hydrogen atom) up to a speed of "lightspeed-3.1m/s"
More commonly expressed as "to an energy of 6.5TeV",
or "Lorentz factor of about 6930"

There have been even faster particles inferred from their energetic demise, like the very energetic cosmic ray particle dubbed the "[oh my god particle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oh-My-God_particle)" which has been calculated to have moved at 99.99999999999999999999951% of lightspeed.

That's the easy part of your question.

At those sorts of velocity the effect of gravity is *so many* magnitudes weaker than the other forces acting upon and within it, that you need a very capable calculator to carry enough digits to keep track, so there have been no observational experiments to actually see if the atom is still subject to gravity, simply because no possible experiment would be sensitive enough. By many, many, *many* magnitudes!

But still, nothing in the theory states that gravity acting on it would change. The atom most certainly does not "outrun gravity", as even photons which propagate *at* the speed of light are still subject to gravity. This is easily proven from gravitational lensing observed by astronomers.

Answer (score 0):

Understanding **rest mass** will help:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mass_in_special_relativity

---

In 2015 these were done:

U.S. Department of Energy's Brookhaven National Laboratory in New York, has just begun pumping liquid helium into 1,740 superconducting magnets to chill them to near absolute zero (minus 273 degrees Celsius, or minus 459 degrees Fahrenheit). At that point, the magnets can run indefinitely without losing any energy.

The team will then steer beams of gold ions — gold atoms stripped of their electrons and positively charged — into each other at **nearly the speed of light**, creating scorching temperatures of 7.2 trillion degrees Fahrenheit (4 trillion degrees Celsius). That's 250,000 times hotter than the sun's fiery core.

The experiments will run inside the 2.4-mile-long (3.9 kilometers) underground atom smasher, called the Relativistic Heavy Ion Collider (RHIC), for 15 weeks at 100 billion electron volts (GeV) per colliding proton or neutron. (The protons and neutrons inside the gold nuclei collide into one another inside RHIC.)

https://www.livescience.com/43079-atom-smasher-investigates-big-bang.html

Comment: This is very helpful, thank you.